# Mayúscula al usar la barra «/» al inicio de frase

Tags: ortografía, uso-de-mayúsculas

En una frase como:

> Encima/debajo del armario.

Se usa la barra colocada entre dos palabras, para indicar la existencia de dos opciones. Mi pregunta es si «Debajo» debería ir en mayúsculas o no, ya que no encuentro ninguna fuente oficial que lo comente. Es decir:

> Encima/**Debajo** del armario.

Lo que he encontrado es un artículo sobre *barra* de la RAE: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bYvzHZDvGD6fr29gvU

Sé que tengo otras opciones para reescribir la frase, pero no me interesan, quiero utilizar la barra para que quede lo más corto posible.

Comment: Jllodra: interesante lo que te dicen los de Fundéu, me sorprende. Nótese que contestar tu propia pregunta no solo es correcto, sino lo recomendable: [Can I answer my own question?](/help/self-answer). Edita pues la pregunta eliminando esta parte y añádelo como respuesta. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me contesto a mí mismo. Escribí un correo a Fundéu con esta pregunta exactamente y recibí esta respuesta:

[image: Fundéu]

Answer (score 3):

Cuando escribimos

> Encima/**debajo** del armario.

Al fin y al cabo estamos utilizando la barra *Para expresar sintéticamente una disyunción entre dos o más opciones posibles entre las que se establece una oposición o alternancia* ([ortografía - RAE 2010](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Ortograf%C3%ADa-%20RAE%202010-Signos%20auxiliares.htm)).

Por tanto, la frase es equivalente a:

> Encima **o debajo** del armario.

que escribimos con *debajo* en minúscula.

Por tanto, lo correcto es usar la minúscula pues así se escribe la frase en su versión extendida.

Answer (score 2):

En el enlace al DPD que has puesto tienes la respuesta (o es una errata, no sé si existe una regla):

> b) Colocada entre dos palabras, o entre una palabra y un morfema, indica la existencia de dos o más opciones posibles. En este caso tampoco se escribe entre espacios y puede sustituirse por paréntesis (→ paréntesis, 2c): **El/los** día/s pasado/s; Querido/a amigo/a.

Está escrita la primera con mayúscula y la segunda con minúscula.

Comment: Lo vi, preferiría una respuesta que me saque de dudas con garantías, me interesaría saber si también estaría aceptado que la segunda palabra empezara con letra mayúscula, pero muchas gracias por contestar.

Comment: Ni en la barra ni en las mayúsculas sale nada, ya miré. Supongo que se mantiene lo de "la primera palabra después de punto".